# "Invalid or nonexistent document" error occurs when opening design element in domino designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a local replica. From domino designer, when I open any design element, I get this error "Invalid or nonexistent document".

But this error didn't occur on server copy. Now you can ask you don't you work directly on server copy. the point is, it's very large db and have serveral xpages and custom control, etc.,. so building the db on remote server copy is painful for me. so work on local copy, save, build, and replicate to server copy.

what I have tried so far.

- deleted local replica and created new replica. still error
- replaced with my latest template. still error
- felt some design elements have corrupted. so replaced both server & local replica with blank template to remove all design elements. and again replaced with latest app template. still error.
- ran load fixup on server copy and replicated in local. still error

do anybody have a clue on this issue or any workaround to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens if you open the database in designer on another machine?

Comment: do you use "Enforce a consistent Access Control List across all replicas" ? (see ACL / Advanced) if so just add in your local names (NAB) the groupe having manager (or at least Designer access).

Comment: also did you "remove" the DB from the Domino Database Designer navigator and then open (from your local) again

Comment: @MichaelRuhnau: I can't open my local replica in another machine. And I don't think it would be a problem with designer. Because, I am able to open all design elements on server copy. Also other applications's local replica works fine.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: I haven't enabled "Enforce a consistent Access Control List across all replicas" on my replica. And also I have removed my db from designer, restarted DDE, again tried opening. I tried this many times. I even deleted cache.ndk. But no luck.

Comment: can you compact the database? maybe this resolve it ;-)

Comment: What if you make a copy of the original database on the server, you include only the design elements, you give the file an extension .ntf (so now you have a template database), you create a local replica of the template database, does that allow you to open design elements?

Comment: @FrankvanderLinden: I did compact but still the same error.

Comment: @D.Bugger: Thanks a lot. Your approach works fine for me. I created a master template on local and I do refresh with server db each time I build. But still I keep the replica without any clue on how to resolve it.

Comment: More guesswork, just a long shot actually: do you happen to have a PostOpen script (see Code/Database Script) that opens a document that's not available locally? If so, can you disable it?

Comment: I don't have any databasescript on my db. But this is concern when we open the db in Notes Client, because we are on designer, so this will not be a constrain I think..

Answer (score 0):

This may sound strange but I have solved weird things before doing this.

Close Notes and designer.  Load Task Manager and make sure all Notes Tasks are ended.

Try to following:

```
from the notesprogram folder run ncompact -c path\dbname
delete \notesprogram\data\Cache.ndk
delete \notesprogram\data\log.nsf
rename \notesprogram\data\workspace folder to workspace.sav
rename desktop8.ndk *.sav
rename bookmarks.nsf *.sav
```

Launch notes and designer then test.  If it works then great.  If not rename everything back.  Note, renaming the above will lose your preferences etc.

Comment: I have tried this and still no luck. But my all other local replica db are working fine in designer other than that particular corrupted local replica. And so I don't think I have problem in my workstation.